# Cannot access application in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Hi I installed the new version of the play framework 2.0. Now I am trying to connect to the sample application from the tutorial but something seems not to be working. Here is what i did:

**Create the "todolist" application:**

`play new todolist`

play! 2.0, http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist

What is the application name?
 
>todolist

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

1 - Create a simple Scala application
  2 - Create a simple Java application
  3 - Create an empty project

> 2

OK, application todolist is created.
Have fun!

**Execute play command:**

$ cd todolist 
$ play

Getting org.scala-tools.sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.11.2 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-tools.sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    37 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (7324kB/127ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/project
[info] Set current project to todolist (in build file:/home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/)

play! 2.0, http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

Execute the run command:

`[todolist] $ run`

[info] Updating {file:/home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/}todolist...
[info] Done updating.
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

**Now I try to connect to the site http://localhost:9000**

I get the following output:

[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/app/controllers/Application.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Problem processing dependencies of source /home/evermean/Code/playWorkspace/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$ref : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: controllers/routes$javascript : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[info] play - Application started (Dev)

I really do not know what to make of that, perhaps someone has an idea on this one. I guess I'm doing something wrong but cannot see where my mistake lies. I hope some can help.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though the JDK you are using is too old. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot, my javac version was 1.7.0 and I had to set it back to 1.6.0_26 to get play to work. I will update my post with the steps I took to resolve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same problem I could run/start the application using jdk 7u5. But when I used dist and java -cp it would not work. I needed to revert back to jdk-6u23 for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Many time java and javac are of same version but play framework / activator will use JAVA_HOME which can be pointing to different version than java and javac.So check all are same:

`echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
javac -version`

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2675

Comment: java -version and javac -version were different for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem. I didn't want to believe it was a JDK version error with play 2.0. Thought about it for 10 mins and realized I didn't have scala installed. Once scala was install it got rid of those errors.

Comment: Don't forget to clean and recompile the project too!

Comment: I was getting these errors when moving my play projects from one environment to another (Windows to Linux). Running `play clean projectname` did the trick.